# How can I fit two overlapping gaussians using linear least squares fitting?

Tags: python, numpy

First off, I created a [jupyter notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/dl.dropbox.com/s/gfwigke21br7hqz/Linear%20Least%20Squares%20Fitting%20of%20Gaussians.ipynb) to show the code properly. [Please take a look](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/dl.dropbox.com/s/gfwigke21br7hqz/Linear%20Least%20Squares%20Fitting%20of%20Gaussians.ipynb).
Second, I'm using linear least squares fitting rather than non-linear least squares fitting for speed. The problem I'm trying to solves involves fitting a large number of gaussians on a spectrum image for electron microscopy, and our current nlls algorithm is slow. It requires fitting within bounds, which is why we are not using `numpy.linalg.lstsq`

I'm trying to use `scipy.optimize.lsq_linear` to do a simple fit of two gaussian components (`g1` and `g2`) with fixed sigma and centre components, to a 2D array `G`that is a list of different mixes of those two gaussians.

First off, defining the gaussian:

```
def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
    return np.exp(-np.power(x - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.)))
```

Then creating the components:

```
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
g1 = gaussian(x, -0.5, 0.5)
g2 = gaussian(x, 0.5, 0.5)
```

And then creating two sets of data to fit to by mixing the components:

```
G1 = 5*g1 + 8*g2
G2 = 2*g1 + 2*g2
G = np.stack([G1,G2]).T
```

I take the transpose of the stack because the `lsq_linear` function requires the data to be of shape `(m, n)` where `(m,)` is the shape of the component to be fit.

I fit the components one by one through

```
g1_res = lsq_linear(G, g1)
g2_res = lsq_linear(G, g2)
```

which should give me the weight of the component for each mix in `g1_res["x"]` in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html).
Multiplying the weights with the components returns:

```
g1_fit = [g1*fit for fit in g1_res["x"]]
g2_fit = [g2*fit for fit in g2_res["x"]]
```

However, the fit (first mix is shown below) is incorrect. Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
plt.plot(x,G.T[0], label="mixed_signal")
plt.plot(x,g1_fit[0], label="gaussian 1")
plt.plot(x,g2_fit[0], label="gaussian 2")
plt.legend()
```

[image: Fit of gaussians to data]

Answer (score 0):

You mixed something up. You are fitting all measured spectra using 1 component. Instead, you want to fit each spectrum using both components. Therefore, the things need to be swapped:

```
g = np.stack([g1,g2]).T

g1_res = lsq_linear(g, G1)
g2_res = lsq_linear(g, G2)



g1_res["x"]
# --> array([ 5.,  8.])
g2_res["x"]
# --> array([ 2.,  2.])
```

By the way, if you have many spectra and the shape parameters  of the gaussian (as given here [+-0.5,0.5]) are always the same but not known or the shape is the same but does not even correspond ideally to gaussian, then you might want to try Principal Component Analysis.
There are already Python packages for it.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.

Comment: I've used PCA and ICA before, and it isn't really applicable in this case - we're trying to fit components of known centre and sigma, but with in some cases they have very small amplitudes and ICA gets a bit tricky.

Comment: Ok, then I guess you're on the right way. Is there anything else or should we close on this?

Comment: Let's close this. Thanks for your help. I'll ask again should I need to!